# How to mask the message senders id in receiver's device using android api?

Tags: android, smsmanager

I am working on a api to mask the id of the message sender so that apps which have permission to read sms from a specific sender are not able to recognize the sms.

For example if sender of the message is 123 it will be received as sent from 456.

Is it possible to do it using SMSManager or any other api in android?

Comment: Are you asking how to replace or override Android system APIs?

Comment: No.There are some apps which scan messages of type OTP.I am searching for an api to bypass the scanning of those messages and force to scan some other senders messeges.